# SVD of a $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algorithms, singular-values

I am trying to implement an efficient, ad-hoc method to perform the SVD of a $3\times3$ matrix.

I know how to obtain the Eigen values of such a matrix, by direct resolution of the characteristic equation (a cubic) and a little of vector calculus.

I don't want an iterative method but a direct one. Preferably without complex numbers. Can you help ?

Comment: If you can calculate the eigenvalues of a $3 \times 3$ matrix efficiently, why not obtain the eigenvalues of $A^*A$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I am wondering if there is a shortcut.

Comment: would [something like this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/analytical-expression-for-the-eigenvectors-of-a-3x3-real-symmetric-matrix) work?

Comment: You might find [this approach](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.6291.pdf) more practical.  If I have understood it correctly, then it is indeed non-iterative.

Comment: You could also try [this approach via cross-products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#Eigenvectors_of_normal_3%C3%973_matrices), once you have a single eigen-pair.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: yes, I am looking for analytical solutions. But the references you pointed at are about the Eigenproblem, not SVD.

Comment: Finding the SVD of $A$ is equivalent to solving the eigenproblem for (the positive definite matrix) $A^*A$ (or $A^TA$ if you're talking about real matrices)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I want to know if there's a shortcut.

Comment: right, that's why I looked for shortcuts towards the eigendecomposition of a $3\times 3$ symmetric matrix, since any such shortcut would help with your problem as well.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I already have the "shortcuts" for the Eigenvalues/Eigenvectors. I am looking for a similar SVD method that doesn't use the "squaring" trick and goes straight to the point.

Comment: These shortcuts exploit the symmetry of the squared matrix, which your eigenvalue/vector methods presumably don't

Comment: In this Wikipedia page, you find straight formulas for the $2\times2$ case, but not $3\times3$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Analytic_result_of_2_×_2_SVD

Comment: How about finding $\max_v \lvert Av \rvert^2$ subject to $\lvert v \rvert= 1$ using Lagrange multipliers. Or by using a parametrisation of the sphere

Comment: @manonlaptop: interesting, I will investigate the equations.

Comment: @manonlaptop: ironically, Lagrange multipliers immediately lead to the Eigenvalues of $A^TA$ !